# GET .json file 404 not found when loading a smart contract

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, blockchain

I am currently building a blockchain based app. For the starting point I was following the freeCodeCamp.org tutorial for a To Do List (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coQ5dg8wM2o&t=2367s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org), but instead of a to do list I want to extend this to a message exchange.

Unfortunately I am having trouble with loading the contract on the website. The code to load the contract sits in eth-info-ex/src/app.js and is as follows:

```
loadContract: async () => {
        const ETHINFOEX = await $.getJSON('./ETHINFOEX.json')
        //create a truffle contract - a js representation of a smart contract that allows to call functions on it
        App.contracts.ETHINFOEX = TruffleContract(ETHINFOEX)
        App.contracts.ETHINFOEX.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvide("http://127.0.0.1:7545"));
        //console.log(ETHINFOEX)
        App.ETHINFOEX = await App.contracts.ETHINFOEX.deployed()
    },
```

The ETHINFOEX.json file is in the following path: eth-info-ex/build/contracts/ETHINFOEX.json

When I load the app by npm run dev I get the following output:

```
> eth-info-ex@1.0.0 dev
> lite-server

** browser-sync config **
{
  injectChanges: false,
  files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
  watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
  server: {
    baseDir: [ './src', '.build/contracts' ],
    middleware: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ],
    routes: { '/vendor': './node_modules' }
  }
}
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ---------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://153.19.246.137:3000
 ---------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 ---------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./src
[Browsersync] Serving files from: .build/contracts
[Browsersync] Watching files...
23.01.14 12:17:59 200 GET /index.html
23.01.14 12:17:59 304 GET /bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
23.01.14 12:17:59 304 GET /bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
23.01.14 12:17:59 304 GET /truffle-contract/dist/truffle-contract.js
23.01.14 12:17:59 200 GET /app.js
23.01.14 12:18:00 404 GET /ETHINFOEX.json
23.01.14 12:18:36 304 GET /bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
23.01.14 12:18:37 200 GET /bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map
23.01.14 12:18:37 200 GET /bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js.map
```

And in the browser the following error:

```
jquery.min.js:4 

GET http://localhost:3000/ETHINFOEX.json 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
n.<computed> @ jquery.min.js:4
getJSON @ jquery.min.js:4
loadContract @ app.js:49
load @ app.js:11
await in load (async)
(anonymous) @ app.js:59
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
load (async)
add @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
sa @ jquery.min.js:3
on @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ carousel.js:496
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
```

I have tried changing the browsers (I tried Edge, Google Chrome and FireFox), I also tried running google with the --allow-file-access-from-file and I also tried editing the path to the file to various combinations:
ETHINFOEX
./build/contracts/ETHINFOEX.json
./contracts/ETHINFOEX.json
and even with the whole path including the drive it is not seen or the web browser states it does not have access to a private path.

I have also tried checking the github repository of freeCodeCamp.org including any repositories made by other users with updates to newer versions but unfortunately I did not find an answer

Has anyone encountered such issue? I would really appreciate any help